# read bytes string from file in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

The content of a file is like following, and the file encoding is utf-8:

```
cd232704-a46f-3d9d-97f6-67edb897d65f    b'this Friday, Gerda Scheuers will be excited \xe2\x80\x94 but she\xe2\x80\x99s most excited about the merchandise the movie will bring.'
```

Here is my code:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        tokens = line.split('\t')
        print(tokens[1])
```

I want to get the right answer - "this Friday, Gerda Scheuers will be excited - but she's most excited about the merchandise the movie will bring."

```
print(b'\xe2\x80\x94'.decode('utf-8')) #convert into ASCII
```

But I can't read the bytes from a file. If I open a file with bytes, I need to decode the line to splite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the bytes literal to bytes:

Then, decode it to get string object:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(r"b'excited \xe2\x80\x94 but she\xe2\x80\x99s'")
b'excited \xe2\x80\x94 but she\xe2\x80\x99s'
>>> ast.literal_eval(r"b'excited \xe2\x80\x94 but she\xe2\x80\x99s'").decode('utf-8')
'excited — but she’s'
```

---

```
with open(file, 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        tokens = line.split('\t')
        # if len(tokens) < 2:
        #    continue
        bytes_part = ast.literal_eval(tokens[1])
        s = bytes_part.decode('utf-8')  # Decode the bytes to convert to a string
```