# How to retrieve correct value of a UTF-8 encoded (from unicode) string from a file from Python3 which was encoded using Python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I am moving my application from Python2 to Python 3. The application saves configuration to a file, and one of the attributes is encoded into utf-8 before saving.

Eg: username='ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ' is saved as '\xe1\x9a\xa0\xe1\x9b....x9a\xb1' (converted data type being str)

Since this config file will be retained across migration, when I try to retrieve user name, I cannot decode this back to unicode as in python3, str object has no attribute decode. Ideally the saved value in file should be treated as bytes, but since python2 does not do it, it creates problem.

I cannot convert this into bytes object as it changes the whole string, tried the same.

Cannot change the current application code as it is already on production.

I tried appending b' manually before the string, which did the trick. But that's a hack. Tried ast.literal_eval but again that's not working.

Pseudo Codes currently, which work fine on Python2 (before migrating to python3):

```
1. To save value in text file:
fp=open(filename,'w')
encoded_name=name.encode('utf-8')
fp.write(encoded_name)
fp.close()

2. To retrieve:
fp.open(filename, 'r') #or rb
encoded_name=fp.read()
fp.close()
return encoded_name.decode('utf-8)
```

Expected results:
Retrieved username from the config file should be treated as bytes instead of str.

Comment: "str object has no attribute decode." Can't you just read it as a byte string then decode it? Such as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337633/8150685. Or maybe `open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
fp.open(filename, 'r')
```

then you don't need to `decode` anything, it's already a unicode string.

But if you use

```
    fp.open(filename, 'rb')
```

it should be decoded with `encoded_name.decode('utf-8')`