# Convert string containing "b'…'" to unicode

Tags: python, string, unicode, decode

I try now for several hours to find a solution for this problem.
I need to read in a generated CSV file that has the headers of the columns in a format like this:

```
"b'Device Name' (b'')"
```

or even

```
"b'Bezugsz\\xc3\\xa4hler' (b'Wh')"
```

I want to convert these strings to Unicode. However, until now I'm out of luck. All examples with encode or decode I found so far didn't lead in a useful direction. I need to get rid of the `b'…'` part as well as the `\x` escapes.

I hope someone here has some useful information. :)

edit: as requested the desired output:

```
"Device Name ()"
"Bezugszähler (Wh)"
```

the first case is easy to achieve with replace(). But I look for a solution for the second case, which would then naturally include the first case.

I tried solutions with ast.literal_eval() but this chokes on the parentheses. Solutions with .encode().decode() also did not work as expected.

Comment: Are you saying the headers literally have the characters "b quote Device Name quote"?  That is a huge screwup by whoever created those files.  You can use `import ast` / `ast.literal_eval(s)` to convert those to byte strings, which you can then decode.

Comment: And, by the way, in order to decode those, you will have to know what character set they are in.  \xc3  is not UTF-8.

Comment: @TimRoberts but `b'Bezugsz\xc3\xa4hler'.decode('utf-8')` returns `'Bezugszähler'` (there isn't  alone `\xc3`).

Comment: @JosefZ  You're absolutely right, I read that string incorrectly.  C3 A4 absolutely is UTF-8, so you should have everything you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read bytes string from file in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337544/read-bytes-string-from-file-in-python3)

Comment: Hi everyone for your suggestions so far. I'm a bit further now, but still finished.
My strings are more complicated to deal with than I thought…
So I removed all "b'" and single ' with .replace. Because .literal_eval choked on this:
"b'Device Name' (b'')" (multiple b'…') in the same string.
But now it chokes on "Device Name ()" giving "invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)".
I suspect it's due to the (empty) parentheses. No idea how to deal with that now. :(

Comment: Ok. Wrapping the string in additional quotes solved this problem:

`word = '"'+word+'"'`

But now I get this from literal_eval: `"BezugszÃ¤hler"`. so the encoding is somehow off.

This is the same result I got from `string.encode().decode('unicode_escape')`. It seems strings are really hard…

Comment: I'm currently looking into regular expressions to solve this. I'm honestly out of my league here. :/

Comment: @TimRoberts yes it is a screwup. By me several years ago, when I started with Python. ;)
However, at that time I did give that not much thought. I thought, when Python creates this it should be able to read this. Now I know better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do this:

1. Use regex to find the faux-bytes
2. Use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert them to actual bytes
3. Decode bytes to strings
4. Insert back into a template

```
headers = [
    "b'Device Name' (b'')",
    "b'Bezugsz\\xc3\\xa4hler' (b'Wh')"]

# ---

import ast
import re

def f(string):
    faux_bytes = re.findall(r"b'.*?'", string)
    real_bytes = [ast.literal_eval(f) for f in faux_bytes]
    decoded = [s.decode() for s in real_bytes]
    return '{} ({})'.format(*decoded)

result = [f(h) for h in headers]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Device Name ()', 'Bezugszähler (Wh)']
```

Comment: I thank you so much.↑↑  I still don't understand completely why this works, but it _does_. **:)**     – I just needed to add two lines that takes into account that one header that is fine. **:D**    – 
This kept me busy so long and yes I learned much from this. Again.     –   
I will need to go back to my old generator script to fix that output. I don't know yet what I will learn from this. **:D**